# How to avoid Tivoli Storage Manager error ANS4042E: "Object name ... contains unrecognised characters and is not valid."

Tags: tivoli, localization, tsm

We are using the Tivoli TSM Backup/Archive client to back up user
files on a largish multi-user system.  Users come from different
countries and thus can create files according to multiple locales.

However, the Tivoli `dmsc` client insists that all file names are
valid in the locale it was started in (e.g., `root`'s locale) and does
not backup files that are not valid in this locale:

```
Sending of object '.../x<B2>+y<B2>=z<B3>' failed
ANS4042E Object name '.../x<B2>+y<B2>=z<B3>' contains one or more unrecognised characters and is not valid.
```

I'm looking after either a config option that turns off file name
validation, or a locale that makes any byte string valid.  (E.g.,
ISO-8859-15 strings cannot contain bytes in the numerical range
128-159 which gives the error above.)

Is there a way to avoid this error and back up *all files*, regardless
of the validity of their names in a locale?